# Javascript - how to remove all characters after a certain set of characters?

Tags: javascript, string, split, substring

I have a filename stored in a cookie, ex. filename.jpg but in IE for some reason it adds some characters after ".jpg"

How can I remove all the characters after ".jpg"?

I only find solutions for removing n number of characters, but the problem is that I'm not sure if the number of characters will remain constant, so I would like to treat it as undefined.

Comment: look into `indexOf` and `substring`...

Comment: And regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution could be, for a variable named `filename`, use:

```
filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf('.jpg') + 4);
```

See [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
var string="your string here";
string.replace(/(.+?\.jpg).*/, "$1");
```

example:

```
"filename.jpgSS348*%&%&$8239SomeMagicHappeningSheat.jpg".replace(/(.+?\.jpg).*/, "$1")
```

returns

```
"filename.jpg"
```

*Note: greediness oprator `.+?`.*